# Can symlinks be used in /etc/cron.d/?

Tags: cron, symbolic-link, configuration-management

I'm trying to implement a configuration mechanism that allows in a certain project to deploy through svn a cron configuration.

I immediately thougt that what I should do is cerate symlinks from /etc/cron.d/ to my project's cron file (which in turn is controlled by a vcs), but that seems to not be working.

I found some old forum messages referring that symlinks were not supported and other saying that they are. Which is it?

Is there anything else or any other good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 29):

According to `man crond`

> CAVEATS
>
> All crontab files have to be regular files or symlinks  to  regular  files,  they must  not be executable or writable for anyone else but the owner.  This requirement can be overridden by using the -p option on the crond command line.  If inotify  support  is in use, changes in the symlinked crontabs are not automatically noticed by the cron daemon. The cron daemon  must  receive  a  SIGHUP  signal  to reload the crontabs.  This is a limitation of the inotify API.
>
> The syslog output will be used instead of mail, when sendmail is not installed.

It annoyed the living crap out of me as well, In short yes you can use symlinks however, if not a regular file or a symlink to a regular file, it must use `-p` switch.

Comment: You will also find that the file must be owned by the user cron is running jobs for; for example, if a symlink `/etc/cron.d/bobsjob` points to a file owned by user "bob" cron will fail with a syslog message `WRONG FILE OWNER (/etc/cron.d/bobsjob)`.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have a user named "www-data" owning the cron file, I'm currently getting the WRONG FILE OWNER error in the syslog. How can I make Cron execute using the user "www-data". I don't want to make root own the file.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `sudo -u www-data crontab -e` and add it to the www-data user's crontab. It'll then run as user `www-data`. Remember to remove the explicit user column, since it doesn't exist in user crontabs.

Comment: Will that place the file inside `etc/cron.`? I was under the impression crontab tool would place the task somewhere else.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You are correct, calling `crontab -e` is not what you want in this case.  I'm looking but haven't found a way to run a user crontab as a non-root user.

Answer (score 16):

This has security implications. The scripts in /etc/cron.d/ are run by root with root privileges. It's a bad idea to symlink scripts there that are owned and writable for non-root users, since your system could be compromised that way

Answer (score 6):

I'd check the cron manpage for your version of Ubuntu (I assume we're talking Ubuntu on this forum!):

> Files  in  this directory have to be owned by root, do not need to be
>   executable (they are configuration files, just like /etc/crontab) and
>   must conform to the same naming convention as used by run-parts(8): they must consist solely of upper-  and  lower-case  letters,  digits,
>   underscores, and hyphens.  This  means  that they cannot contain any dots.

As Florian points out, if this file is writable by non-root users, it's a security hole because the jobs will be run by root (for whoever is named as the job owner in the file). Also note, therefore, that

> This directory can contain any file defining tasks following the format used in /etc/crontab, i.e. unlike the user cron spool,
>   these files must provide the username to run the task as in the task definition.

i.e. pop the username in before the command to run.

Comment: *This means that they cannot contain any dots.* pay attention to this. I had a dot into the link name. It was the culprit for my not-running jobs for me. Plus: the file itself MUST end with a CRLF